# Does ADODB fail on output parameters with optional input parameters?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic, adodb, output-parameter

I have a stored procedure in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with an optional input parameter and an output parameter like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateTicket]
(
    @TrackingCode varchar(25),
    @EmailAddress varchar(250) = null,
    @Ticket varchar(1000),
    @UserID int,
    @TicketID int output
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO dbTicket (TrackingCode, EmailAddress, Ticket, UserID)
        SELECT 
            @TrackingCode, @EmailAddress, @Ticket, @UserID

    SELECT @TicketID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    RETURN @TicketID
```

When I invoke the stored procedure without the optional parameter in SSMS it works fine:

```
DECLARE @TicketID int

EXEC [dbo].[spCreateTicket]
    @TrackingCode = 'xOCDUv289u403k5h24s5869vK',
    @Ticket = 'Something broke!',
    @UserID = 64307,
    @TicketID = @TicketID OUTPUT
```

But when I try the same thing through ADODB in ASP classic like this:

```
SET cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = HelpDeskConnection
cmd.CommandText = "spCreateTicket"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("@TrackingCode",adVarChar,adParamInput,25,RandomString(25))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("@Ticket",adVarChar,adParamInput,1000,Ticket)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("@UserID",adInteger,adParamInput, ,Session("UserID"))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter ("@TicketID",adInteger,adParamOutput)
cmd.Execute
TicketID = cmd.Parameters("@TicketID")
```

it does nothing, `@TicketID` is left `Empty`, and the ADODB.Connection contains this NativeError 8162:

> "The formal parameter \"@UserID\" was not declared as an OUTPUT
>   parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output."

I use ADODB to call stored procedures without optional parameters all the time.  Is this a known defect in ADODB, or do I need to do something particular to get it to work when there's an output parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out [the ADODB default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is to ignore the parameter names and simply pass them to the sproc in the order appended.

Hence, in the example given, `@Ticket` was passed to the sproc as `@EmailAddress`, `@UserID` was passed as `@Ticket`, and no output parameter was passed at all!

If you want ADODB to match parameters by name you have to set the ADODB.Command `.NamedParameters = True`.