# Force ADODB Connection.Errors to throw or alert in VB?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, runtime-error, adodb

The most subtle errors will often hide inside an `ADODB.Command` object.  In VB and ASP, by default, if you don't explicitly check the `.Errors` property, you nothing will tell you that something has gone wrong with the database.

Having just discovered this, and having a large codebase with hundreds of ADODB calls: Is there any single setting that can cause these Command objects to throw a server error?  Or do I really have to wrap or append every ADODB operation in a `IF cmd.Errors ...` check?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers sorry disagree never needed to check it yet, most of the time *(in a SQL Server)* environment at least it just contains warnings not errors. If a query is going to fundamentally fail it will throw a provider error which triggers a `HTTP 500 Internal Server` Error. Unless you are looking for a very specific condition it's not much use.

Comment: @Lankymart - Basically, if there's something in there, I want the server to be very loud about it.  [In this example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39185679/2662901) it did not trigger a 500, and I couldn't figure out why the query wasn't working until I dug in and discovered this (at least in that case) silent property.

Comment: That's simple always declare all parameters regardless of whether they are optional or not, that's lesson one of using `ADODB.Command` parameters. If a value is optional or you want to use the default, don't set the parameter `Value`. This way you will never have that problem.

Comment: @feetwet if it didn't trigger an error, your problem is not ADO but an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code.